# How to mock logging in Django Rest Framework unittest?

Tags: python, django, logging, django-rest-framework

I have a unit test that tests whether an unauthorized user can `GET` a certain url. I want to use `unittest.mock` to mock the logging in the request. How can I point the decorator to use the correct logger ? My test looks like:

```
@patch(what goes here???)
def test_response_list_not_authenticated(self, mock_logging):
    url = django.core.urlresolvers.reverse("project-api:response-list", args=[6])
    response = self.client.get(url, format="json")
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, rest_framework.status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
    self.assertEqual(mock_logging.error.called, True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just put the path to your `logging` object, let's say for example you have the following in `"myapp.views"` file

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Then in your test you do:

```
@patch('myapp.views.logger')
def test_response_list_not_authenticated(self, mock_logger):
     ...
     # asserts about logger
     self.assertTrue(mock_logger.error.called)
```